# Manga where the female lead plays with a dog that transforms into a human

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can't remember much except the female lead plays with a dog the turns out to be a female main character. I think the female lead is reincarnated into the villains body.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This could really use some more details.  Who is the villain, and why are they villainous?  What kind of dog?  What are their names?  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Mostly black and white if I remember right, the dog transforms into a girl with black hair and I'm sure she has underlings/ followers who dont like the female lead

Comment: Can you clarify the characters involved? I'm assuming this is a villainess story, where there's a protagonist of the original story, and she's separate from the protagonist of the actual manga. Is this correct? Are you absolutely positive that the black haired character was this original-protagonist, and not a guy? In other words, are there three people involved? 1. The protagonist of this story, a reincarnated person  2. The original protagonist, a bully everyone loves 3. A black haired person that transforms into an animal and back?

Comment: You maybe right Honestly it's been about two years since i read it and i can't remember much, If no one knows no worries.

Comment: @Neptune if you do remember more, or you think any of the comments are right in their details please do [edit] them in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be *[I'm a Banished Villainess, but I'm Accompanied by a Fluffy Creature?! My Peaceful Life Starts](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tsuihousareta-akuyaku-reijou-desu-ga-mofumofu-tsuki-slow-life-hajimemashita)*. Some of the details match, others don't but could be misremembered.

> I'm Airi, an office worker who reincarnated as an otome game's villainess, Irene. I was on cloud nine ready to start my second life when I was expelled from the academy. With the help from the townspeople, I opened a quaint café. I was supposed to enjoy my new, peaceful life when suddenly "a fluffy creature" appeared! I tried to feed him my signature sweets, but...?!

The synopsis covers the "reincarnated into the villain(ess)" part. Irene is the villainess in the story and her role is to be hated by others. Liliana is the heroine of the original story, and her role is to be loved by others. Liliana and her followers harass Irene, blaming her for mischief they perform, which covers another aspect of the question.

[image: Everyone just goes along with it.]

Neither of these characters can transform into an animal. This is another character, a male with black hair that seemingly doesn't appear in the original story, and thus isn't bound to love Liliana and despise Irene.

[image]

When it rains, he transforms into a tiger - but Irene explicitly thinks he's a dog. In a flashback, it is shown that she took care of him while he was transformed into a tiger and fed him cake, while everyone else chased him away for looking like a stray dog.

[image]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Animal Transformation` and `Reincarnated as the Villain/ess`.

Comment: It's this i think i was mixing multiplr manga together